# Querying email addresses indexed by lucene

Tags: email, search, lucene, indexing

If I'm trying to retrieve dave@gmail.com, searching "dave" will work as will "dave@gmail.com".

But searching for "dave@gmail" won't work. The query takes place inside a Java servlet.
I believe that the problem may lie with the full stop splitting

How can I fix this so that "dave@gmail" will return "dave@gmail.com"?  Email addresses may also contain other domains (like .co.uk)

thanks

Comment: When you say you have dave@gmail.com in you index, how does it get there? I had a similar problem where I was reading from a file and adding to my index. What I didn't realise was that I was running apache tika to get text from said file. The parser for apache tika tokenised the email ids separately so by the time the text got to the lucene analyzer, the damage was already done. If you are using such an implementation and you DO find an answer. Let me know too.

Answer (score 3):

Lucene uses 'Analysers' to tokenise and index your documents. Likewise, analysers are used to tokenise the user search query.

A common mistake is to use a different analyser for indexing than for searching, both must match for you to get the results you expect (search [this doc](http://oak.cs.ucla.edu/cs144/projects/lucene/index.html) for "common mistake").

The [standard lucene tokeniser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_0_0/api/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizer.html) recognses email strings and indexes them as one token.

It will index dave@gmail.com as [token:dave@gmail.com]. However, it's possible that the analyser you are using to tokenise your query  (or if you are constructing the query manually) is breaking it up into 3 tokens, splitting at the non alpha-numeric characters. So you might be searching for 3 adjacent tokens: [tok1:dave] [tok2:gmail] [tok3:com], which don't exist.

[Query.toString](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_4_0/api/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#toString%28%29) will probably "pretty print" the Query you are submitting to Lucene which may help you debug.

Comment: I'm using the standard tokeniser for both.  However, if the whole email address is a single token, then does that explain why I don't get my desired result? Eg. If I were to search "yah", would I expect "yahoo" to be included in the search results?

Comment: It depends, it's possible that during indexing you're using a chain of analysers, some may index the email as 3 tokens (dave, gmail, com) and another may index the whole thing as one (dave@gmail.com). This would explain why you get a hit for dave. Can you use Luke to check the contents of your index - see if you can see the token 'dave@gmail.com' as  single entity. Also try a toString on your Query, to make sure you are submitting "dave@gmail.com"

Comment: As a followup, we're using the standard analyzer and it IS breaking the email up into separate terms; it's not recognizing emails. We're on Lucene 9, so things have greatly changed. Any chance you have any insight for more recent versions of lucene?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.UAX29URLEmailTokenizer
```

or

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.KeywordTokenizer
```

tokenizer to search by email address

Answer (score 1):

you can Use the Fuzzy as a Analyser in Query Search. this will approximate the result set by user define levenshtein Distance(LD).

Answer (score 0):

The [accepted answer to using Lucene to search for email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014/using-lucene-to-search-for-email-addresses/20468#20468) shows how to build your own tokenizer and analyzer for email addresses. Creating your own gives you precise control over how you'd like to store and retrieve email addresses in Lucene.