# How to find email id from lucene indexed data

Tags: lucene

Currently I am using lucence 7.4 and my requirement is to extract the list of files containing email id under a particular root folder

Being a newbie I did one mock exercise to gain experience on lucene and as of now I am able to index the root folder recursively for all files and the search pattern for a sample string (ex : oracle.com) is returning  list of files to me.

Moving forward I am unable to understand how I can extract only files having occurrences of email id ?

Both my indexer and searcher java classes are using StandardAnalyzer.

In my main class I tried using below regex but no luck..:(

```
tester.search("[a-z]*.[a-z]*?oracle.com")
.
.  
 private void search(String searchQuery1) throws IOException, ParseException, org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException  {
  searcher = new Searcher(indexDir);
  long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//create a term to search file name 
  Term term1 = new Term(LuceneConstants.CONTENTS, searchQuery1); 

  //create the term query object 
  Query query1 = new RegexpQuery(term1); 

  TopDocs hits = searcher.search(query1);
```

Please Guide.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/19014/6039846 , it seems to be exactly what you need

Comment: Thank you @rojobo for guiding me on this.As of now, I was able to proceed after using _org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.UAX29URLEmailAnalyzer_ Analyzer in both indexing and searching methods. The problem with the standard analyzer was it was breaking the email address into 2 different tokens after finding @ hence didn't suited our need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.UAX29URLEmailAnalyzer* Analyzer can be used incase we are using lucene7.4.0